# Asp net MVC 4, Creating a simple forum

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to asp net Mvc and I'm trying to create a simple forum in mvc 4.  I can create and list threads and posts but I cant seem to figure out how to add a new post to a existing thread. In other words I want to be able connect several Posts to a specific `ThreadId`.

So what is the best way to accomplish this, should I pass a value in an `@ActionLink` to my `PostController Create method` with a `ThreadId` value? Or can I somehow handle this exclusively in my PostController? Any code samples or hints are very much appreciated.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Thread
{
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? PostDate { get; set; }
    public string ThreadText { get; set; }
    public string ThreadTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}    

public class Post
{        
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set;}
    public string PostText { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? PostDate { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("Thread")]
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to achieve what you want. Here I present you an approach using Strongly Typed View.

I assume you have a view called **ViewThreadDetail** which have a list of posts belong to a given **threadId** and you can also submit a new post in there.

ThreadController.cs:

```
public class ThreadDetailViewModel
{
    public Thread Thread { get; set; }

    public Post NewPost { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ViewThreadDetail(int id)
{
    // load thread from database
    var thread = new Thread(){ ThreadId = id, ThreadTitle = "ASP.Net MVC 4", Posts = new List<Post>()};
    // assign ThreadId of New Post
    var newPost = new Post() { PostTitle = "", PostText = "", ThreadId = id };

    return View(new ThreadDetailViewModel() { Thread = thread, NewPost = newPost });
}
```

ViewThreadDetail.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ThreadDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewThreadDetail";
}

<h2>ViewThreadDetail</h2>

<p>List of Posts:</p>
@foreach (var post in Model.Thread.Posts)
{
    <div>@post.PostTitle</div>
}

<p>Add a Post:</p>
@Html.Action("NewPost", "Post", Model.NewPost)
```

You will need a PartialView called NewPost to submit new Post:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Post

@using(Html.BeginForm("Add", "Post"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.PostTitle);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.PostTitle);

    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.PostText);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.PostText);

    //A hidden field to store ThreadId
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.ThreadId);

    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

PostController.cs

```
public ActionResult NewPost(Post newPost)
{
     return PartialView(newPost);
}

public ActionResult Add(Post newPost)
{
     // add new post to database and redirect to thread detail page
     return RedirectToAction("ViewThreadDetail", "Thread", new { id = newPost.ThreadId });
}
```

Comment: Thank you namkha87 for your quick response, this helped me a lot and i got it working. I also learned some stuff on the way.

Comment: I thought i got everything to work but apparently I'm not populating this list: `Posts = new List<Post>()};` So this doesn't show: `post.PostTitle` in my ViewThreadDetail.cshtml. Not sure what im doing wrong. From what i gather the new thread object is supposed to have a list of Posts. Im passing a `id=item.threadId`into this controller from a ActionLink.

Comment: read the comment, this line is just an example to help you figure out, you must load the thread from the database. You can use Entity Framework to do that

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me again. Figured it out and used this to load a thread: `var loadThread = db.Posts.Where(p => p.ThreadId == p.Thread.ThreadId);` and `Posts  = new List<Post>(loadThread)`.